# Woocommerce coupon code for cart items with custom price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

While WooCommerce lets you have a custom price for the product while it's being added to cart using `"woocommerce_before_calculate_totals"`, the system still calculates the subtotal using the original price while it checks the coupon code against cart totals.

This creates an issue when the coupon code has to work on orders above a certain amount. If the original price is less than the required subtotal, the coupon will throw an error even if the custom price is valid for the offer.

I was unable to find a proper hook to alter the behaviour but I managed to fix it temporarily by creating a new function like the one below. It checks for the coupon code and removes it if the subtotal is more than the desired amount which is 2999 in this case.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'apply_matched_coupons' );
function apply_matched_coupons() {
global $woocommerce;
$coupons = $woocommerce->cart->get_applied_coupons();
 if(in_array('yourcoupon', $woocommerce->cart->get_applied_coupons())){
     $cart_subtotal = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal;
     if ($cart_subtotal < 2999) {
     $removeCoupon = WC()->cart->remove_coupon( 'yourcoupon');
      $something = wc_print_notice( __( 'Minimum spend is Rs. 2999', 'woocommerce' ), 'notice' );

     } 
}
}
```

is there any other solution that is more efficient as this can never be trusted when more and more coupons are generated?

Comment: Wow, this is interesting. I've never actually experienced this myself. Are you applying your custom prices during `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` hook? Or are you doing it as the products are added to the cart initially?

Comment: @Frits: Yes. I am using `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` as that's what I have seen as the widely accepted method.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out all I need to do was to update the `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-discounts.php` file. Despite the fact that both my file and the Github file show the coupon validation code as 3.2.0, they seemed different when it comes to calculating the subtotal.